# MS Access Append Query is corrupt

Tags: ms-access

A recent Microsoft security update KB 4484119 has had an adverse effect and makes append queries corrupt.

Does anyone know if there any patches for this yet?

We have tried the manual work around, which is ok for us who know how to do this but our clients do not have expertise or confidence to try this.

Comment: Update Office on any PC's having this problem

Answer (score 2):

Progress will be posted on the official support page:

[Access error: "Query is corrupt"](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/access-error-query-is-corrupt-fad205a5-9fd4-49f1-be83-f21636caedec)